# intellisence support for metatag in as3 with flashdevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am looking for intelligence support for meta tags in flash develop same as flash builder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: Which version of FD do you use? Have you looked for it in the forum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently FlashDevelop offers only 2 generators for meta tags:

- right-click on a file in Project panel to generate an [Embed] meta at cursor position,
- if you have something like `dispatchEvent(new Event(SomeEvent.FOO))` in your code, put your cursor on `FOO`and press Ctrl+Shift+1 to generate the [Event] meta before the classe declaration.